# Integrating Tabulator in vue.js

Tags: javascript, vuejs3, tabulator

I'm trying to integrate Tabulator in vue.js to create some datatables screens.

To do this i'm following the official documentation of Tabulator, available via this [link](http://tabulator.info/docs/5.3/install).

The tabulator installed package (tabulator-tables) version is 5.3.4, and I'm using Vue.js 3.2.37.

The code below contains the instantiation of the datatable as shown in the documentation inside the TheWelcome.vue file representing TheWelcome component..

```
<script setup lang="ts">
 import WelcomeItem from "./WelcomeItem.vue";
 import DocumentationIcon from "./icons/IconDocumentation.vue";
 import ToolingIcon from "./icons/IconTooling.vue";
 import EcosystemIcon from "./icons/IconEcosystem.vue";
 import CommunityIcon from "./icons/IconCommunity.vue";
 import SupportIcon from "./icons/IconSupport.vue";
 import { Tabulator, FormatModule, EditModule } from "tabulator-tables";
 Tabulator.registerModule([FormatModule, EditModule]);
</script>

<script lang="ts">
 const columns = [
 { title: "Name", field: "name", width: 150 },
 { title: "Age", field: "age", hozAlign: "left", formatter: "progress" },
 { title: "Favourite Color", field: "col" },
 { title: "Date Of Birth", field: "dob", hozAlign: "center" },
 { title: "Rating", field: "rating", hozAlign: "center", formatter: "star" },
 {
  title: "Passed?",
  field: "passed",
  hozAlign: "center",
  formatter: "tickCross",
 },
];

let data = [
 { id: 1, name: "Oli Bob", age: "12", col: "red", dob: "" },
 { id: 2, name: "Mary May", age: "1", col: "blue", dob: "14/05/1982" },
];

new Tabulator("#example-table", {
  data: data, //link data to table
  debugInvalidOptions: false,
  columns: columns,
});

</script>
<template>
  <div id="example-table"></div>
</template>
```

This component is imported and used inside the App.vue file

relevent code:

```
<template>
 <TheWelcome />
</template>
```

The index.html kept unchanged

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
 <head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8" />
   <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
   <title>Vite App</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div id="app">
   <div id="example-table"></div>
  </div>
  <script type="module" src="/src/main.ts"></script>
</body>
```

newcomer to vue.js, any tip, explanation, orientation would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```js
<script setup lang="ts">
import { onMounted } from 'vue';
import ...
import { Tabulator, FormatModule, EditModule } from "tabulator-tables";
Tabulator.registerModule([FormatModule, EditModule]);

const columns = [...];

const data = [...];

// NOTE: the part below must be inside <script setup>
onMounted(() => {
  new Tabulator("#example-table", {
    data: data, //link data to table
    debugInvalidOptions: false,
    columns: columns,
  });
})
</script>

<template>
  <div id="example-table"></div>
</template>
```

from: https://tabulator.info/docs/5.4/frameworks#vue3-composition